# Jenkins Grails Plugin fails with StackOverflowError

Tags: grails, jenkins

I've got a Grails project that I'm currently building with Jenkins and the Grails plugin.  Sometimes it seems that it throws a StackOverflowError while starting up Grails.  It doesn't seem to do this all the time, and if I restart the Jenkins web app, the error will go away.

The error is

```
Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
Build step 'Build With Grails' marked build as failure
```

Is there anything I can do to get to the bottom of this error?  The console output here isn't very useful unfortunately.

## EDIT

I added

```
--verbose --stacktrace
```

to the build target to try to get more output.  Problem is I didn't get anything new when it failed.  Same error, output looks like

```
/opt/local/grails/bin/grails clean --verbose --stacktrace --non-interactive

Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
Build step 'Build With Grails' marked build as failure
```

Comment: Nope. Though it seems to be happening less frequently now.

Comment: I figured out my problem. Apparently the wrong user started the bamboo service. So mine was related to permission errors.

Answer (score 2):

An infinite loop is causing this issue that is resulting from the lack of a .inputrc file in your user home directory.

put a .inputrc file in your user home directory and you should be all set.

see [this E-mail thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/StackOverflowError-when-starting-Grails-2-3-2-td4651274.html) for more details.

NOTE: I have reported this as a bug ([Grails-1162](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11662)) in the Grails Jira

Comment: Is this on Windows?  Can you be more specific on what an .inputrc file is?

Comment: This is Linux. I'm not sure if there is a similar issue in windows or not.

Comment: I had similar problem in windows environment. I opened the command prompt in administrative mode and did the same. In my case it was working.

Comment: Thank you so much for this Randyaa... I've been having a nightmare trying to get an old version of Grails to work and the absence of a .inputrc file was to blame. I'd never have found that myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try disable uglyfying javascripts:

add

```
grails.assets.minifyJs = false
```

to your Config.groovy

This helped me. Previous answer (adding .inputrc) did not.